# ¿Como tomar solamente en cuenta solo una parte de un campo de un array? o ¿Como eliminar cierta parte de ese campo?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo este arreglo de videos y en campo de el link solo quiero tomar en cuenta la parte despues del = que seria { https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNR7j1ItZ68 } y yo quiero { UNR7j1ItZ68 }

```
     videos= [{
                "Desscripcion": "Este es uno de ejemplo",
                "Link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNR7j1ItZ68"
            }];

 constructor() { console.log(this.video) }
```

Se que en la parte de html se puede poner un |slice pero como seria desde el ts? que deberia hacer para lo que quiero obtener?

Se podria con un if pero de que manera seria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la funció `split` la cual funciona de la siguiente manera:

```js
const videos = [{
  "Desscripcion": "Este es uno de ejemplo",
  "Link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNR7j1ItZ68"
}];

const videoArray = videos[0].Link.split('=');
console.log(videoArray, videoArray[1]);
```

Debes tener en cuenta que si la url a la que deseas tomarle el valor, siempre va a tener un parámetro puedes usar el bloque de cógido como te lo suministré.

De lo contrario, puedes hacer el split primero separando todos los parámetros de la url haciendo el `split('?')` y tomando la segunda parte de la misma, la cual va a contener una cadena conformada por todos los parámetros. Para separar cada parámetro se hace otro split al caracter &, es decir `split('&')` y ya quedaría cada parámetro separado lo que hay al lado izquierdo del = es la key y al lado derecho del igual sería el valor.

Otra forma como puedes hacerlo y considero que es la mejor opción, es aprovechar la interfaz Router de angular y la interfaz URL. Comparto el código que he realizado como ejemplo en angular:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'params-url';
  url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNR7j1ItZ68';

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Pasamos el string de la url que tenemos global como parametro en la interfaz URL
    const nUrl = new URL(this.url);

    /**
     * Luego de la conversion de el string a la interfaz le removemos el protocolo al string
     * ya que si lo dejamos no podemos realizar el parseo correctamente con la interfaz Router de angular
     */
    const urlTree: UrlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.url.replace(`${nUrl.protocol}//`, ''));

    /**
     * Teniendo el parseo realizado procedemos a sacar los valores de los parametros, en este caso
     * el valor del parametro v
     */
    const v = urlTree.queryParams['v'];
    console.log(v);
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Amigo Jorge si me funciono muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, eres de lo mejor

Comment: Me alegro haber sid de ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Saludos a ti también amigo